# SceneKit shader modifiers

Tags: swift, scenekit, metal, metalkit

I'm writing a 3D space game using SceneKit and I'm pretty happy with it so far, but I'm starting to hit some limitations and would like some advice.

1. I have a sphere which represents a star that sits on a point light, and I'd like to add some effects to this to make it look more realistic.  I think I should use the sphere's shaderModifiers to do this, but I'm not sure which modifiers I should be looking at i.e. to achieve a lens flare effect.  Infact if anyone can give me a clear explanation of the differences between: ShaderModifiers, SCNProgram and SCNTechnique that would be great!
2. I'd like to draw a 1px circle to represent an orbit.  I've tried using a cylinder that is really thin, but this results in some visual artefacts (the ring seems to have gaps at larger distances and break up). Any ideas how I can do this and maintain a nice smooth circle?

Answer (score 0):

1. The shortest way to have a `flare effect` for SceneKit models is to use a `CoreImage` framework's [capabilities](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/04/creating-lens-flare-filter-in-core-image.html).
2. For making a visible orbit use a regular PNG-image technique with premultiplied alpha channel (RGBxA). Look at [this link](https://www.sciencefriday.com/educational-resources/scale-solar-system-orbits-and-satellites/) to find out how a png image with orbits looks like (save a file). And if you wanna automatically orient a plane toward a camera use a constraint.

And here's a code:

```
let orbitsOnPlane = SCNPlane(width: 10, height: 10)

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named:"overlayOrbits.png")

orbitsOnPlane.materials = [material]

let orbitNode = SCNNode()
orbitNode.geometry = orbitsOnPlane

let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: orbitNode)

cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
```

[image]